# trying to have a fragment talk to its parent Activity when the fragment is in a share module

Tags: android

I am trying to have my fragment (in a share module) comunicate with its parent activity.
I tried using the following code to call a callback in the parent activity
  ((MainActivity)getActivity())
I got a error saying MainActivity is undefined. I'm assuming this is because the fragment and Activity are in different modules. (NyLibary and app)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it's in another module you'll need to import MainActivity class in your fragment.

By the way calling the parent activity this way is not the best thing you can do, in my opinion you should have interface represents the One who should implement your functions, this way you save the modularity for your fragment.